# How can i slow down the Animation Speed of ALL Animations in a Project?

Tags: animation

Hey i made a Animation and everything is going way to fast, is there an option to slow down ALL Animations in a project and render it again but slower?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if you want to slow down the animations or the render:

- To slow down the animations themselves, go into the *Dopesheet*, put your blue cursor at frame 0 (the cursor position will determine the operation center), select all and scale up with <kbd>S</kbd> + drag.

[image]

- To slow down the render itself, i.e. increase the amount of frames as if you were shooting in slow motion, go into the *Properties* panel > *Output* > *Dimensions* and play with the *Time Remapping* values. The *Old* and *New* values allows you to set the ratio between the current speed and the one you want, for example to double the time you need to choose a ratio of 1(*Old*)/2(*New*), to add 20% choose 10/12 or 5/6, etc. If you’ve slowed down by a half you’ll need to double the *Frame End* value, otherwise you’ll only render half of the whole animation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply scale all f-curves.
[image]

1. Turn off Only Selected (red)
2. Set pivot to 2D Cursor (blue)
3. Go to frame 1, hit s -> x and move your mouse or type in 2 for twice as slow.

Note that this won't effect drivers (unless they are simply bound to an animated property) or animation nodes.
The time remap suggested by @moonboots should work as well, but tweaking your animations with those settings may be rather tedious.